# Protractor array in AngularJS 1.3.14

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

Since I updated AngularJS to version 1.3.14 I'm having problems with array in my Protractor tests.

My application has a auto refresh feature that refresh the page that i'm testing every 10 seconds.

If I test a specific value inside a repeater, when the refresh hits I'm getting errors like "element is not attached to the page document".
This is a simple example:

```
describe('Test', function() {
    it('Go to page', function() {
        browser.get(someURL);
    });

    it('check value', function() {
        expect(element.all(by.repeater('some repeater')).get(0).element(by.css('.some-css')).getText()).not.toBe('not this text');
    });
});
```

I'm locating the repeater every time I check the expect but still i'm getting error.
Any idea?

I'm using protractor 1.8.0 on chrome.